# Is there a way to specify different widths for columns in CSS3?

Tags: css, css-multicolumn-layout

I would like to use CSS to present a two-column layout. The markup I am using is this

```
<div style="-webkit-column-count: 2;
            -webkit-column-rule: 1px solid black;
            -webkit-column-width: 80px;
             margin-left:20px;margin-top:20px;">
    <div id="picturebox" style="">picture box</div>
    <div id="nme">name</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way to give one column a width of 20px and one column a width of, say, 80px?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, there isn't a way.

The feature is designed for content that flows between equal columns.

Answer (score 18):

Technically it's not possible to do it with the [multi-column property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts) only but for a 2-column layout you can accomplish that by setting a negative `margin` on one of the sides.

```css
div {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: lightgreen;
}

ul {
    -moz-columns: 2 auto;
    -webkit-columns: 2 auto;
    columns: 2 auto;
    -moz-column-gap: 80px;
    -webkit-column-gap: 80px;
    column-gap: 80px;
    margin-right: -80px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Lorem</li>
        <li>Lorem</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[See JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5vn7ksLj/2/)

Comment: So following the logic behind the above nice idea, you can accomplish this with a 3-column layout as well.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [grid property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_grid.asp):

```css
.container-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 20px 50px; /*columns widths*/
  height: 40vh;
}

.col-1 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.col-2 {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-grid">
  <div class="col col-1"></div>
  <div class="col col-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The grid is unable to break a child element into columns. Each element will always be in one of the columns as a whole.