# custom column sizes creation using column property

Tags: html

i've the below html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .newspaper {
                -moz-column-count:2;
                /* Firefox */
                -webkit-column-count:2;
                /* Safari and Chrome */
                column-count:2;
                -moz-column-gap:40px;
                /* Firefox */
                -webkit-column-gap:40px;
                /* Safari and Chrome */
                column-gap:40px;
                -moz-column-rule:4px outset #ff00ff;
                /* Firefox */
                -webkit-column-rule:4px outset #ff00ff;
                /* Safari and Chrome */
                column-rule:4px outset #ff00ff;
            }
            .newspaper1 {
                -moz-column-count:3;
                /* Firefox */
                -webkit-column-count:3;
                /* Safari and Chrome */
                column-count:3;
                -moz-column-gap:40px;
                /* Firefox */
                -webkit-column-gap:40px;
                /* Safari and Chrome */
                column-gap:40px;
                -moz-column-rule:4px outset #ff00ff;
                /* Firefox */
                -webkit-column-rule:4px outset #ff00ff;
                /* Safari and Chrome */
                column-rule:4px outset #ff00ff;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><b>Note:</b> Internet Explorer 9, and earlier versions, does not support the column-rule property.</p>
        <div class="newspaper">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.</div>
        <div class="newspaper1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat, vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius.</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/29GHW/

here when i run it i get a 2 column layout, followed by 3 column. but here my problem is, in 3 column layout, i want the left column to take 80% of the width and the second column to take 20% of the width, please let me know how do i achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to specify different width to columns in CSS3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453522/is-there-a-way-to-specify-different-width-to-columns-in-css3)

Answer (score 1):

I think that is not possible.

From [here:](http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/WD-css3-multicol-20010118/)

`column-space-distribution`

*This property describes how to distribute space in the case where CWPB is smaller than the content width of the element.*

And `column-width-policy`

*This property describes how to interpret 'column-width'. The 'flexible' value indicates that the width of columns can be increased to fill all the available space. The 'strict' value indicates that 'column-width' is to be honored.*

They are not implemented in the most of the browsers, and there is nothing specified about fixed percentage in the documentation.