# CSS3 Column Styling Issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a 2 column div and would like to style each column separately. I am using

```
columns:70px 2;
-webkit-columns:70px 2; /* Safari and Chrome */
-moz-columns:70px 2;
```

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7t63M)

I would like for the column on the left to text align right and the column on the right to text align left.

I know I could perhaps custom make my columns as 2 divs with paragraphs, add display inline block and set the sizes and style but i was wondering if there was a way to target a specific column via the method used above.

Comment: Please post your HTML.

Comment: @Lowkase http://jsfiddle.net/7t63M/

Comment: I wasn't even aware of these vendor prefixes, I'm unsure of your HTML/CSS knowledge, if you're a beginner, you could create two columns and style them differently like so: http://jsfiddle.net/7t63M/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, no you can't! Because the css division that causes the columns doesn't break the element on two separated elements. So every other properties applied are shared between the columns
Here are the properties you can use on CSS3 columns: http://davidwalsh.name/css-columns

Similar question: [Is there a way to specify different width to columns in CSS3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453522/is-there-a-way-to-specify-different-width-to-columns-in-css3)